# Create Calculated field in Pivot Table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, pivot-table, powerpivot

I need the expert help. I want to implement one formula for particular column on Pivot Table created by VB code.

I have written the code that will create the Pivot table with Count the Repeat Data and would like to next column will populate with predefined formula while generating the pivot table by button click event.

Formula will be implemented on column “C” as below by using PIVOT Table generation code using VBA module

=IF(AND(B2>=0,B2<=2),1,IF(AND(B2>=3,B2<=5),2,IF(AND(B2>=6,B2<=10),3,IF(AND(B2>=11,B2<=15),4,IF(B2>=16,5)))))

**Source worksheet (Rawdata):**

[image]

Current code and  Pivot table :

**My current VBA source code for generation of Pivot Table:**

```
Sub PivotTableModule()

'Insert Pivot Table
'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Pivot").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivot"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("Pivot")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Rawdata")

DSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

'CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
TableName:="SalesPivotTable")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")

'Insert Row Fields
With PTable.PivotFields("FailureMode")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

'Insert Data Field
With PTable.PivotFields("FailureMode")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Description = "Sum of FailureMode"
.Function = xlCount ' xlSum
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
.Name = "RepeatCount"
End With

End Sub
```

**Current Output (Pivot Generated by Code)**

[image]

**My Expected Pivot Table would be as below :**

**Formula on Column 'C' while creating the Pivot table
=IF(AND(B2>=0,B2<=2),1,IF(AND(B2>=3,B2<=5),2,IF(AND(B2>=6,B2<=10),3,IF(AND(B2>=11,B2<=15),4,IF(B2>=16,5)))))**

[image]

**HI, I have tried with the Pivot Table Calculated Fields but I am getting the error. I don't know the code is correct or not.**

```
Sub PivotCalculatedFormula()
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable")

'for empty cells in the data area of a PivotTable report, show a specified value, using the PivotTable.NullString Property:
PvtTbl.NullString = "0"
PvtTbl.DisplayNullString = True

PvtTbl.CalculatedFields.Add Name:="RPN", Formula:="=IF(AND(RepeatCount>=0,RepeatCount<=2),1,IF(AND(RepeatCount>=3,RepeatCount<=5),2,IF(AND(RepeatCount>=6,RepeatCount<=10),3,IF(AND(RepeatCount>=11,RepeatCount<=15),4,IF(RepeatCount>=16,5)))))"
 

With PvtTbl.PivotFields("RPN")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Function = xlSum
.Position = 3
.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
.Caption = "RPN-%"
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Search "Calculated field" in Excel pivot table.

Comment: But I want to generate Pivot Table automatically using VBA code as I have mentioned.

Comment: You can add that calculated field through VBA. Also, just for info.. [Excel FREQUENCY Function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-frequency-function)

Comment: Hi Naresh, I have tried the "Calculated field" but I am getting the error as above. I have added my updated code at the end on main request. Please guide me and correct my code.

Comment: I have tried with added the below code in Pivot Generating code at the end.  
Worksheets(1).PivotTables(1).CalculatedFields.Add "RPN", _
 "=IF(AND(RepeatCount>=0,RepeatCount<=2),1,IF(AND(RepeatCount>=3,RepeatCount<=5),2,IF(AND(RepeatCount>=6,RepeatCount<=10),3,IF(AND(RepeatCount>=11,RepeatCount<=15),4,IF(RepeatCount>=16,5)))))"